# React components positioning

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, react-component

I'm trying to position the react components and having hard time figuring out with CSS flexbox.

I have 3 react components as below

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <div className = "header">
      <h1>Connect cruAMS and Security Center</h1>
    </div>
    <br></br>
    <div className="App">
      <Cruams />
      <SecurityCenter />
      <UserContainer />
    </div>
  </>
  );
}
```

Currently it's location is like below.

```
Cruams      SecurityCenter     UserContainer
```

What I want is

```
      Cruams      SecurityCenter

           UserContainer
```

How can I do this using CSS flexbox? Or is there a different way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to make your css too complicated, a simple top margin can help you here:

```css
.App {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.cruams {
  display: inline-block;
}
.securityCenter{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
} 
.userContainer {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div className = "header">
  <h1>Connect cruAMS and Security Center</h1>
</div>
<br></br>
<div class="App">
  <div class="cruams">cruams</div>
  <div class="securityCenter">securityCenter</div>
  <div class="userContainer">userContainer</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using any extra divs:

```
<div className="container">
   <Cruams className="half-width" />
   <SecurityCenter className="half-width"/>
   <UserContainer className="full-width" />
</div>

.container {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.half-width {
   flex-basis: 50%
}

.full-width {
   flex-basis: 100%
}
```